# Why are my donuts appearing lIke this

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

So a few months ago I did the donut tutorial in cycles, then I opened it in eevee. Unfortunately,there appears to be an outline. I have the Eevee toon shader add on, but I can't find it in my preferences, so I'm confused as to how there are outlines. My nodes are similar to the cycle nodes, but with the principled shader.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Blender the outline called freestyle, you can find it in the properties window under the render tab.

[image]